# How to align different size lettering flush with the top of a line?

Tags: vertical-alignment

What I'm looking for is for something similar to CSS's vertical-alignment tag in order to align text of different sizes flush with the top of a line vs the bottom of the line.

With the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\tiny smaller text should be aligned level with} the following text here
\end{document}
```

I get:
[image]

What I would like is this:
[image]

I haven't been able to find a way to do this for some reason, so any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`f-\height\relax}{\tiny
    smaller text should be aligned level with} the following text here
\end{document}
```

This raises based on the height of `f` in the larger text, you may want to use the height of a capital such as `t` or `\ht\strutbox`, depending.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question has been asked a few times before, but I wasn't able to find it using google or search, but SE's related search found it for me.

Here's one way it can be done using \raisebox:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny smaller text should be aligned level with} the following text here
    \end{document}
```

Comment: that raises it but doesn't necessarily align the tops.

Answer (score 0):

[`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides a `valign=t` option, changing the anchor to be at the `t`op:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

some regular text
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\tiny smaller text should be aligned level with}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{the following text here}

\end{document}
```